# YADCF custom_func not calling custom function

Tags: yadcf

I have a database field that contains either integer 1 (representing the value 'document') or integer 2 (representing the value 'email') and I use datatables to format/display these integers as the words 'document' or 'email' within the table column. I would therefore like to use YADCF to be able to select 'document' or 'email' and have datatables filter the resultset accordingly. 
[Link to screen shot of table column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZS1y.jpg)

I have used the custom_func feature as follows (code stripped down for brevity), but regardless of all other aspects of the datatable looking and working correctly, with a filter selector looking as expected and holding the selected value, and no console errors, my custom function is not being called. I have tried manually calling the custom function immediately before initialising YADCF, to check the scope, and it is being called just fine. Can anyone see anything obviously wrong please?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function customFilterDocEmail(filterVal, columnVal) {
        alert('customFilterDocEmail called');
        var found;
        if (columnVal === '') {
            return true;
        }
        switch (filterVal) {
            case 'doc':
                found = columnVal === '1';
                break;
            case 'email':
                found = columnVal === '2';
                break;
            default:
                found = 1;
                break;
        }
        if (found !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
})


var table = $('#table').DataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/datatables/getJson/doctext/doctexts',
    type: 'POST', 
    data: function(d) {d.CSRFToken = '****';}
  },
  stateSave: true,
  responsive: true,
  pageLength: 25,
  order: [[0, 'asc']],
  columns: [ 
    { data: 'txt_type', width: '10%' },
    { data: 'txt_title' },
    { data: 'txt_name', width: '20%' },
    { data: 'link', orderable: false, width: '5%' },
  ],
  }
});

yadcf.init(table, [ 
  { column_number: 0, filter_type: 'custom_func', custom_func: customFilterDocEmail,
    data: [{ value: 'doc', label: 'Document' }, { value: 'email', label: 'Email' }] },
  { column_number: 1, column_data_type: 'text', filter_type: 'text', filter_delay: 500, filter_default_label: '', },
  { column_number: 2, column_data_type: 'text', filter_type: 'text', filter_delay: 500, filter_default_label: '', },
  ], 'footer');
```

- YADCF Version: 0.9.3.beta.11
- DataTables Version: 1.10.16

**UPDATE:** I haven't a clue what I'm doing wrong above, but I have come up with a little hack that saves having to use 'custom_func' and a custom filter. I've used the standard 'select' filter type but intercepted the filter string within the filter() method of my DatatablesSSP script thus:

```
$str = $requestColumn['search']['value'];    
// returned search values for doctext 'txt_type' are Document/Email, so we need to map these to 1/2.
if ($column['db'] == 'txt_type') {
    if ($str == 'Document') { $str = '1'; }
    if ($str == 'Email') { $str = '2'; }
}
```

This works a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the `customFilterDocEmail` function outside of the `$(document).ready`  block so it will be global and *yadcf* will *see it*

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for responding, and for developing YADCF - it's people like you that keep the web progressing. I tried placing the function outside the ready block in the first place and only moved it inside whilst trying various things to trouble-shoot. As you've taken the time to try and help, I've just rolled back my code to before my workaround/hack, and moved the function outside again. Still no call to the function from YADCF :(  That said, I had already tried manually calling the function from immediately before the YADCF initialisation, and the alert told me that it was within scope.

Comment: Thanks, then please provide a test page and will try and help you more, p.s you can see it working in the showcase page

Comment: I've integrated YADCF into a large and complex bespoke application framework in which everything else about Datatables (and YADCF) is working very well. Including my workaround, which is actually cleaner and leaner than the custom filter solution. To reproduce every aspect of the YADCF use as an ajax test page would be difficult, so I'll say thanks for offering, but I'll carry on using the workaround and assume that there's some kind of code clash elsewhere, even though no errors are being triggered. Thanks again for building and maintaining YADCF :)

Comment: ok, in any case the first table in the showcase using the custom filter and you can view source to learn how exactly... http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html